# list index out of range, lendo dado e salvando uma uma váriavel

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá! 
Preciso ler um dado que se encontra em uma lista na posição 13 e se repete a cada 15 valores. Utilizando o seguinte código recebo mensagem de erro:

```
for i in range(0,len(dado),15):
         lat = texto.pop(13+i)
```

A mensagem de erro:
   IndexError: list index out of range.
A array tem 15 mil valores, não entendo o porque deste erro :/

Comment: Imagine que `dado` possui 35 registros. Seu `for` irá definir a sequência 0, 15 e 30, o que fará com que você acesse as posições 13 (13+0), 28 (13+15) e 43 (13+30). A posição 43 não existe na sua lista.

Comment: humm, interessante. Ainda estou aprendendo python. Agradeço a ajuda!